# how to decode mp3 file in c# using NAudio

Tags: c#, mp3, audio-streaming, naudio, decoding

My task is to decode a mp3 file, exclude its header, side information and the optional checksum. I just need the actual data of every frame of the mp3 file.
I have googled a lot but did't find a way !
Can any one tell me a direct way to do that. I am using NAudio to access frames using ReadNextFrame() 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does ReadNextFrame() wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.de/2010/11/merging-mp3-files-with-naudio-in-c-and.html you could change the code to something like that:

```
    public static byte[] GetRawMp3Frames(string filename)
    {
        using(MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream()) {
            Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(filename);
            Mp3Frame frame;
            while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
            {
                output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
            }
            return output.ToArray(); 
        }
   }
```

Then you can process the frame-only bytes by doing this:

```
var btAllFrames = GetRawMp3Frames("MyMp3.mp3");
```

Comment: i have used this method already but it also included header and side information
i only need the actual data without header and all other side info etc...

Comment: I dont think so. Frames should only contain the raw audio data. The header information is stored before headers. Are you sure?

Comment: every frame in mp3 has its own header.but i have to exclude that header
decoder gets information from header and side information and decodes only actual bits of a frame.i wan to do something like this

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looks like this is a dupe question that was answered better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871408/1647114).

ORIGINAL:
Sounds like you want a full MP3 decoder that outputs the main_data chunks instead of decoding them.

Two options:

1. Build your own reader (complete with bit reservoir calculations for layer III), or
2. Remove the audio decode logic from an existing decoder and insert your output logic instead.

There are probably some tricks you can apply that would allow you to short-circuit decoding at least some of the header / side info, but that will take a thorough understanding of the specifications.

If you need a place to start for option #2, try searching for NLayer, JLayer, libmad, or "dist10 source".

Answer (score 0):

Apparently NAudio uses [NLayer](https://github.com/naudio/NLayer).

This worked for me

```
  byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("path/to/file.mp3");
  var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(results);
  var mpgFile = new NLayer.MpegFile(memStream);
  var samples = new float[mpgFile.Length];
  mpgFile.ReadSamples(samples, 0, (int)mpgFile.Length);
```